# Tab indicator is not able to be positioned correctly as expected

Tags: flutter, position, tabbar, indicator

im using tabs for categories. Im facing issue with the indicator

the given is the expected image and what i currently get

[Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAHAq.png)

[Current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgL8p.jpg)

is there any solution so that i can get the indicator as expected. i tried using slack preferred size and all . but no solution was got.

code i use:

bottom: TabBar(
isScrollable: false,
tabs: [
Tab(text: LocaleKeys.all.tr),
Tab(text: LocaleKeys.ranking.tr),
Tab(text:LocaleKeys.special_feature.tr),
],
),

Comment: can you include sample code-snippet that will reproduce the same error

Comment: @Md.YeasinSheikh 
 I have added the code i currently use.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Consider also to read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask